# Use .class file in php

Tags: php

I need to use a .class file to encrypt data.What will be the php code for the following jsp line

```
jsp:useBean id="enc" class="Cryptn" scope="session"
```

or is there another way to do it?

Comment: There is no PHP code to use a Java class...

Answer (score 3):

Your options are:

1. Expose the java functionality in a web-service and call the web-service from php.
2. Reimplement the functionality in php.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can create a new object from a Java class file in PHP. However, you can invoke arbitrary commands from PHP, such as commandline-stuff, i.e.: "java YourClass".

You might be able to use your class that way. Other options are the two @Klaus Byskov Hoffmann mentions.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at the [php/Java Bridge](http://php-java-bridge.sourceforge.net/pjb/) as a starting point.